# select second element of a specified class using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two elements with class of `monkey` on the page, and I want to attach one of them to a on click event listener. they maybe siblings or completely independent elements. Now I want to select the second element (which comes after the first one in html code)...

This will select both of them and the event listener fires twice:

```
const monkey = $(".monkey");
```

I used a lot of things with no luck to select the second element:

```
$(".monkey").get(1); 
$(".monkey")[1]
```

**Edit:**

Here is the relation of two monkey elements one at the top and at the bottom of the image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`jQuery.eq`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) as a function or as a selector.

You can make use of a ternary operator to check whether the number of selected `monkey` elements is greater than 1, and if so, set `monkey` to the second element. Otherwise, don't modify `monkey`.

```js
var monkey = $(".monkey"); //same as $(".monkey:eq(1)")
monkey = monkey.length > 1 ? monkey.eq(1) : monkey;
monkey.on('click', function(){
  console.log('click');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="monkey">first element</div>
<div class="monkey">second element</div>
```

Comment: And How can we check if there is any second element? using `$(".monkey").eq(1)` when there is no second element doesn't return `undefined`!!

Comment: @SaraRee Do you need to ensure that the element exists? If no element is selected adding a `click` event listener won't have any effect.

Comment: I need to check if there is any second element if there is select it if there is only one element then select it somehow I want to select the last element?

Comment: But using `$(".monkey").last()` works only when there is one element ..  if there is second element it will not be selected...

Comment: Yours not working too... I take a picture and edit my question...